# How can I save blog posts?

Tags: support, blog, export

After hearing [from various places](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33026084#33026084) that per-site blogs are probably going to be closed, I considered saving locally in my computer some (or all) blog posts.

Of course, I can save them simply as HTML files. Are there some better ways how to save a blog entry (or how to save all of them at the same time)? For example, is it possible to extract them in the MarkDown+MathJax form? Are blog posts collected and available somewhere in some reasonable format? (Similarly as all content from the site is regularly archived in the form of the [data dump](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-dump/info).)

Comment: Possibly something useful here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StackExchange is moving forward on their plans to discontinue all community blogs, including our blog. The SE team has offered to provide data dumps of the current blog content; in [JNat's](http://stackexchange.com/users/1399708/jnat) own words from the Teachers' Lounge:

> As you've probably heard, we're discontinuing community blogs, and I'm contacting each community to see what they wanna do with theirs, and how we can help. We're defaulting to providing static pages, but are happy to provide data dumps if you wanna put it elsewhere and pick it back up.

I'll provide more details about that when we know more.